Are some passages in "Pedro Páramo" influenced by William Faulkner?
In the Wikipedia article on Juan Rulfo, it is remarked that:

In passages of the novel Pedro Páramo, the influence of American
novelist William Faulkner is notorious, according to Rulfo's former
friend, philologist Antonio Alatorre

This assertion is based on an interview which Alatorre gave to the Mexican newspaper El Universal in 1998, which was published in 2010. For the assistance of the non-Spanish-reading community, I translate below the relevant parts below:

When 25 years had passed since the appearance of Pedro Páramo, Juan
[Rulfo] made some very solemn statements in Excelsior, in which he
commented something more or less like this:
“There are many stories being told about how I wrote Pedro Páramo,
and now I am going to say how things happened so that they stop
telling stories. It is said that there is Faulkner's influence in
Pedro Páramo. It is not true, because when I wrote Pedro Páramo I did not know Faulkner.”

Alatorre was shocked when he heard this, because he knew that Rulfo had read Faulkner well before he had started writing Pedro Páramo, and in fact had recommended Faulkner to him as an author worth reading. Alatorre's view was that Rulfo was simply lying when he said this, seeking to diminish any accusations of Faulkner's influence.
Putting aside any questions of Rulfo lying, either deliberately or through simple forgetfulness, or for that matter whether Alatorre could have been mistaken, the point remains: Are there passages in Pedro Páramo which show evidence of Faulkner's influence?
